# onclick post title in admin area javascript file not working

Tags: plugin-development

I am trying to load a popup when click on post title in admin area and then get the data through meta query and show in popup but in console it's showing error that the js function is not defined. Looks like the file is not including properly I have tried in many ways but still the same.

I am trying to include the file in plugin name 'tasks' and the js file is in `tasks/assets/js/functins.js`

http://prntscr.com/gv2ea2

Here I am including the script file

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','tasks_js_file_func');


 function tasks_js_file_func() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'tasks_js', plugins_url( 'assets/js/functions.js',__FILE__ ), '', '', true);
 }
```

This the function where I am creating onclick for each title

```
function adding_onclick_post_column( $columns ) {

                global $post;

                switch ( $columns ) {
                    case 'new_title':
                        echo'<a href="#" onclick="alert_func();">' . get_the_title( $post->ID ) . "</a>";
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','tasks_js_file_func');
```

Try with this action called `admin_enqueue_scripts` It'll enqueue your js file inside of the WordPress admin area.

Comment: where do you live, I mean country

Comment: can I have your contact detail ?

Comment: I'm from Bangladesh brother.

Comment: Here is my mail address : asrmahfuz8@gmail.com